# Root Cause of Shellshock Bash bug

Tags: bash, shellshock-bash-bug

I don't get the root cause of **shellshock** bash bug such as CVE-2014-6271.
As far as I understand, shellshock happens if there is a malicious code inside the application packet header. 
For example, if HTTP header includes **http-header[Cookie] = () { :; }; ping 192.168.0.1** then it pings to 192.168.0.1. 
However, HTTP header only needs to be set of string variables. Why does Apache ever run bash script? 
Is Apache HTTP header parser composed of bash shell script?
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C's `system()` function, used to execute an arbitrary external command, passes its argument to `/bin/sh` for parsing. (This is specified by POSIX.)

`/bin/sh`, on Linux systems, is commonly a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`.

If Apache invokes *any* external program via `system()`, and an attacker has been able to insert malicious code into any environment variable, it will be passed on to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: And bash will happily evaluate any variable that looks like an exported function (starts with `() {`), to import it as a function. Not stopping at the end of the function definition.

Comment: Which means bash does parse the header right? Ok Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JohnDoyle: What "header"? Bash parses the contents of certain environment variables.

Comment: @KeithThompson OK, so apache would parse the HTTP header then set the environment via bash. I got the point